# How can I delete an AggregateMember on Axon?

Tags: java, cqrs, axon

I have an aggregate `Organization` which can have several addresses. So we have modeled this `OrganizationDeliveryAddress` as an Aggregate Member. On the `OrganizationDeliveryAddress` we command and event sourcing handlers for the entity itself.

Here's my current implementation:

```java
@Aggregate
public class Organization {

  private @AggregateIdentifier
  @NonNull UUID organizationId;

  @AggregateMember
  private final List<OrganizationDeliveryAddress> deliveryAddresses = new ArrayList<>();

  @CommandHandler
  public UUID on(AddOrganizationDeliveryAddressCommand command) {
    val addressId = UUID.randomUUID();
    val event = new OrganizationDeliveryAddressAddedEvent(command.getOrganizationId(), addressId, command.getAddress());
    AggregateLifecycle.apply(event);
    return addressId;
  }

  @EventSourcingHandler
  public void on(OrganizationDeliveryAddressAddedEvent event) {

    val address = new OrganizationDeliveryAddress(event.getOrganizationDeliveryAddressId(), false);
    deliveryAddresses.add(address);
  }

}

 

public class OrganizationDeliveryAddress {

  private @EntityId
  @NonNull UUID organizationDeliveryAddressId;
  
  @CommandHandler
  public void on(RemoveOrganizationDeliveryAddressCommand command) {
    AggregateLifecycle.apply(new OrganizationDeliveryAddressRemovedEvent(command.getOrganizationId(),
        command.getOrganizationDeliveryAddressId()));
  }

  @EventSourcingHandler
  public void on(@SuppressWarnings("unused") OrganizationDeliveryAddressRemovedEvent event) {
    if (organizationDeliveryAddressId.equals(event.getOrganizationDeliveryAddressId())) {
      AggregateLifecycle.markDeleted();
    }
  }

}
```

We want to remove one of the addresses, but it looks like not just the address, but the entire aggregate is deleted.

So here's my question: How can I instruct Axon Framework to remove the `OrganizationDeliveryAddress` Aggregate Member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AggregateMember` is not an Aggregate per se but just a member of another Aggregate. This is why if you call `AggregateLifecycle.markDeleted();` it will mark the Aggregate itself as deleted.

To 'delete' an `AggregateMember` you should do the opposite as adding it, which means you can have an `@EventSourcingHandler` method on your Aggregate listening to the `OrganizationDeliveryAddressRemovedEvent`. This method would be responsible to find the right DeliveryAddress on your AggregateMember (`deliveryAddresses`) or even better a `Map` as you will see below and simply remove it from that. A pseudo-code could be something like this:

```
// Organization.java
...
@AggregateMember
private final Map<UUID, OrganizationDeliveryAddress> deliveryAddressItToDeliveryAddress = new HashMap<>();
...
@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(@SuppressWarnings("unused") OrganizationDeliveryAddressRemovedEvent event) {
    Assert.isTrue(deliveryAddressItToDeliveryAddress.containsKey(event.getOrganizationDeliveryAddressId()), "We do not know about this address");
    deliveryAddressItToDeliveryAddress.remove(event.getOrganizationDeliveryAddressId());
}
```